# Spring framework and Quartz scheduler

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, quartz-scheduler

I have a Spring MVC web application and I want to make use of Quartz scheduler. After reading the docs on Quartz and also on how it integrates with Spring, I am left wondering.

Will Quartz handler run as a separate process independent of tomcat or is it just another maven dependency that I will add be able to schedule within my controllers?.

This is the tutorial that I am reading from https://dzone.com/articles/integrating-quartz-withspring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quartz is just another maven dependency which starts a daemon thread in the background and keeps looking into QRTZ_CRON_TRIGGERS every defined interval, which stores when the job run last time, and when it is going to run next time. You can get more detailed diagram at http://www.javarticles.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/QuartzSchedulerModel.png which will help you understand, how it works internally.

Comment: "Quartz is just another maven dependency which starts a daemon thread in the background" that's pretty neat.

Answer (score 0):

I did it in spring REST service:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.some")
public class ApiApplication {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApiApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

..............

```
@Component
public class ScheduledTasks {

@Scheduled(cron = "0 1 0 * * *")
    public void expiredPromotionsTask() {
        log.debug("expiredPromotionsTask begin");

        try {
            your code here..

            log.debug("expiredPromotionsTask end");
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            log.error(e, "expiredPromotionsTask failed");
        }
    }
```